# Logstash creates pipeline but index is not created

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I am trying to create an index on elasticsearch cloud using a json file. I have created the configuration as given below:

```
input {
        file {
                path => ["/root/leads.json"]
                start_position => "beginning"
                ignore_older => 0
        }
}
output {
        elasticsearch {
                        hosts => ["https://ac9xxxxxxxxxxxxxb.us-east-1.aws.found.io:9243"]
                        user => "elastic"
                        password => "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
        }
}
```

I am able to run the logstash using the command:

```
sudo bin/logstash -f /etc/logstash/conf.d/logstash.conf
```

The logstash starts a pipeline, but I am not seeing any index getting created in elasticsearch:

```
 [INFO ] 2018-11-14 09:16:01.821 [[main]>worker1] file - No sincedb_path set, generating one based on the "path" setting {:sincedb_path=>"/usr/share/logstash/data/plugins/inputs/file/.sincedb_43b5fa3acfcfc04b3df80a7c15c8d991", :path=>["/root/leads.json"]}
[INFO ] 2018-11-14 09:16:01.852 [Converge PipelineAction::Create<main>] pipeline - Pipeline started successfully {:pipeline_id=>"main", :thread=>"#<Thread:0x2fda8150 run>"}
[INFO ] 2018-11-14 09:16:01.944 [Ruby-0-Thread-1: /usr/share/logstash/lib/bootstrap/environment.rb:6] agent - Pipelines running {:count=>1, :running_pipelines=>[:main], :non_running_pipelines=>[]}
[INFO ] 2018-11-14 09:16:01.996 [[main]<file] observingtail - START, creating Discoverer, Watch with file and sincedb collections
[INFO ] 2018-11-14 09:16:02.522 [Api Webserver] agent - Successfully started Logstash API endpoint {:port=>9600}
```

Comment: Can you add `sincedb_path => "/dev/null"` in your `file` input as well?

Comment: @Val I have already tried that.. not working and same output is shown

Comment: Hmm I would remove `ignore_older`, though, that might work better ;-)

Comment: @Val That actually worked, thanks a lot :)

Comment: Can I get to know the exact reason, for this ?

Comment: See answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change your configuration like this:

```
input {
        file {
                path => ["/root/leads.json"]
                start_position => "beginning"
                sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
        }
}
```

Remove `ignore_older => 0` since that will effectively ignore files that are older than 0 seconds :-)
Adding `sincedb_path` makes sure that you can run the pipeline several from the beginning of the file.